# Configuring Xorg.conf for 6 monitor Big Desktop

Tags: xorg, nvidia, multi-monitor

**Update:**

Here are the some things I have attempted when I had some time to battle this.

Linux mint is the only distribution which for some reason Randr can see all 6 monitors. I can configure and turn them all on, but mouse movement is extremely laggy and most window managers crash.

In any other distro, Xorg/Randr only sees two outputs.  So trying to use Randr extention is out of the question. If Xrandr could see all 3 gpu using the nvidia driver, I'd be happy. Perhaps that might perform well enough for me to even move the mouse.

In Mint, the config was nouveau driver, Randr can see all monitors, but performance is so bad I can't even use it.  If I switch to nvidia, cli resolution gets messed up and X sees my 60" screen's dpi as 36 so fonts are so tiny I can't read them. Easy fix though -dpi or "DPI" 96x96 in Xorg startx --. Anyway, w/ nvidia binary driver, Randr can't see anything but the primary gpu.

What I have been able to make work so far is Xmonad and Kwin (two that don't crash). I love Xmonad.

So I've the nvidia binary driver currently on Debian stable 8.2 Jessie. Same config as before. 3 screens, 2 monitors each, X layout is screen 0 on top, 1 and 2 below it side by side. Works well enough, but if I have only one window open, it spans across both monitors. Any splash screen of course opens up in the middle of the two combined monitors on each screen.

If I turn Xinerama off, I can't use my bottom 4 monitors at all, even though I can drag my mouse across them. I can maybe try to launch an xterm on display 0:2 through 5, but that's tedious and requires having to configure my xresources everytime I need to make even the tiniest change. And even w/ this I can't drag windows freely between monitors.

I can however pick up entire screens and move them around to each other in Xmonad, but top screen is 2x1080 and bottom are 2x (2x 1024); 4 screens (each 1024). So moving the screens is doable, but then the resolution is messed up.

If I have 6 screens, one monitors each screen and then combine them all using Xinermama, I can't switch more than 3 monitors in Xmonad.

There really seems to be almost setup that I can find that would work w/ this many monitors. I was thinking about taking out my 3rd 2port gpu and putting in a quadro nvidia w/ 4 ports so I can have total of 8 monitors.

I might find more time to battle this issue, but until then... I'm back on windows as I need to get work done.

If you guys have any tips on WM configs or screen configs or any setup suggestions or tips or something, I'd really welcome them.

Also, anytime I switch to the nvidia binary driver in ANY distro, my dpi changes to 36 (correctly determined by Xorg probably as these are 2 60" LED TVs.) And the cli resolution also changes to I think 8x16 charsize, and basically it no longer uses what could be considerd the 1080p mode of the vga= parameter, I believe vga=367. I went through debian docs and configured /etc/default/grub 2 and modified the resolution and GFXPAYLOAD to keep etc and still no dice. I can't seem to even pass the vga= params anymore as they seem to not be supported by grub 2.

Anyway, lots of issues on linux which require time and attention and which I don't currently have. Soon as I do, I'll figure it out. In the meantime, any tips or suggestions would be tremendously helpful.

Thank you!

**Suse Linux 42.1 Leap** - As of 12/13/15 I'm on Debian 8.2

Linux 4.1.13-5-default #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 26 16:35:17 UTC 2015 (49475c3) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have 6 monitors, 2x 60" on the top, and below them, 4x 19" portrait mode. Each of the monitors is up and running. I can move my mouse across all monitors, but I can't drag windows to any other monitors. Additionally I can't get any kind of a right click menu on anything other than monitors on gtx 275.

I can't seem to get TwinView working either. I have the monitors oriented and positioned like I want, but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to combine them all into one big desktop.

- Nvidia GTX 275 - 2x 60"
- 8400GS - 2x 19"
- 8400 GS 2x 19"

My `Xorg.conf`:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 340.93  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-03)  Wed Aug 19 17:10:48 PDT 2015


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 0 1080
    Screen      2  "Screen2" 2048 1080
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from data in "/etc/sysconfig/mouse"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "IMPS/2"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "yes"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "VIZ E601i-A3E"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 70.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 77.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: unknown, VertRefresh source: unknown
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 1905FP"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: unknown, VertRefresh source: unknown
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 1907FPV"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 275"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8400GS"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8400 GS"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-2: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DVI-I-3: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +1024+0 {rotation=left}, DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=left}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=left}, DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +1024+0 {rotation=left}"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +1024+0 {rotation=left}, DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=left}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

My `Xorg.0.log` is too big to include here, so I have uploaded it [here](http://sprunge.us/JhdO).

I've asked in ##linux and #suse on Freenode and so far no one has been able to figure this out. I'm really hoping that this is possible, otherwise I'd have to use Windows 10 and that's what I'm trying to stay away from.

How do you combine all these monitors into one large display?

Comment: pointed out this link on #linux Freenode: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead (apparently he's decided to move to windows since then)

Comment: I attempted Xinerama as well as Twinview and it just doesn't function like I want. I have to get work done, I can't waste time battling desktop linux.

Comment: Even w/ Xinerama, the window positions are dead center in the middle of the combined desktop. I've been doing dual head on Debian since around 2004~ish w/o a hitch. However a multi gpu setup w/ Xinerama or TwinView works awkwardly at best.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my updated 6 screen Xorg.conf (no Xinerama):

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 340.46  (pbuilder@zam904)  Fri Oct 17 21:29:34 UTC 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" 0 1080
    Screen      3  "Screen3" RightOf "Screen2"
    Screen      4  "Screen4" RightOf "Screen3"
    Screen      5  "Screen5" RightOf "Screen4"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "VIZ E601i-A3E"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 70.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 77.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option "DPI" "96x96"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "VIZ E601i-A3E"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 70.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 77.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option "DPI" "96x96"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 1908FP"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor3"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 1905FP"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor4"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 1905FP"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor5"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 1907FPV"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 275"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 275"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8400GS"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device3"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8400GS"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device4"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8400 GS"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device5"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8400 GS"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-2: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-3: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=left}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen3"
    Device         "Device3"
    Monitor        "Monitor3"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=left}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen4"
    Device         "Device4"
    Monitor        "Monitor4"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=left}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen5"
    Device         "Device5"
    Monitor        "Monitor5"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=left}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

With Xinerma, I lose acceleration and it lags in some cases, but it's usable enough.

I think I finally figured it out.

Thank you Dagmar for the final suggestion. It's closer to where I want to be, but it's not quite there yet.

Status: 90% Solved.

Comment: If I have 6 screens, one monitors each screen and then combine them all using Xinermama, I can't switch more than 3 monitors in Xmonad. <-- For this I need to bind additional keys in Xmonad, as I was told in #xmonad.